# android custom progress Dialog animation not working

Tags: android, android-animation, android-dialog

I wrote custom dialog.Dialog is properly displayed,but at dismiss I want to add animation (slide_out_top).Dialog's gravity is Top.Below is source of dialog:

```
public class MessageDialog extends Dialog {

private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
private TextView mText;
private ImageView mAttentionImage;


private int mBackgroundColor;
private String mMessage;
private int mImage;
private Animation bottondown;
private RelativeLayout body;


public MessageDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MessageDialog(Context context, int custom_message_dialog) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_message);


    WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = getWindow().getAttributes();
    getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
    wmlp.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
    wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
    wmlp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    wmlp.height = 300;
    wmlp.horizontalMargin = 0;
    wmlp.verticalMargin = 0;
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);



    Animation bottomUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),
            R.anim.slide_in_top);

    bottondown=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),
            R.anim.slide_out_top);


    body  = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.u_message_body);
    //body.startAnimation(bottomUp);

    mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.u_message_content);
    mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.u_message_text);
    mAttentionImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.u_message_dialog_image);

    mLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(mBackgroundColor));
    mText.setText(mMessage);
    mAttentionImage.setBackgroundResource(mImage);


    final Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            try {

               dismiss();

                t.cancel();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
    }, 2000);






    findViewById(R.id.u_message_dialog_close).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

}

and this is a my animation xml code

slide_in_top

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<translate
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="-100%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p" />
```

slide_out_top.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:toYDelta="10%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

As i said my  dialog's gravity is Top.Now I want to add slide_out_top animation
at the moment when I dismiss dialog animation not working properly

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple way to do this

1)You can use Dismiss listener

```
@Override
    public void setOnDismissListener(OnDismissListener listener) {
        super.setOnDismissListener(listener);

  body.setAnimation(bottondown);
    }
```

2) You can define styles in onCreate method

```
getDialog().getWindow() .getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.MyAnimation_Window;

and in styles 
<style name="MyAnimation.Window" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">"place Enter anim"</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">"place exit anim"</item>
    </style>
```

EDIT :

Add **`android:toYDelta="-15%p"`** in animation.xml file.

Comment: thanks i tryed it with style.xml file but my dialog gravity is TOP,and my android:windowExitAnimation starting center position.do you know this solution

Comment: <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:toYDelta="100%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" /> 

add   android:fromYDelta="10%p"

Comment: i want to dismis my  dialog after 2 second .how i can wrote my Timer to dismis my dialog and also my animation should work @bpA 52

Comment: @ bpA i understood it but after two second i can dismis my dialog but animation now woking

Comment: i update my code.please see it.in dismis my animation not working

Comment: @ bpA automaticly hided after 2 second ?

Comment: can you edit my code and show me again? thanks  @bpA

Comment: Sure , but please tell me that that why you add only animation on relative layout , why not on whole layout

Comment: thanks men i solved my problem i inserted android:toYDelta="-15%p" in animation.xml file @bpA